# Rabbit MQ fails to start

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I have finished installing RabbitMQ using the following RPM

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v2.7.1/rabbitmq-server-2.7.1-1.noarch.rpm

i installed it like so :

```
$ wget \ http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v2.7.1/rabbitmq-server-2.7.1-1.noarch.rpm
$ rpm --nodeps -Uvh rabbitmq-server-2.7.1-1.noarch.rpm
```

the reason i used --nodeps was because i installed erlang from source and the rpm will try looking for an erlang.rpm dependency ignoring the one on the system.

When i try to start the Rabbit MQ server i get this error :

```
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: line 73: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@
vz129.pid: Permission denied
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_prelaunch,start,[]},{init,start_i
t,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}
```

Im using CentOS release 4.9 (Final).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Who is the owner of this directory /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia and what user are you running rabbitmq as?

Comment: thanks for replying, root is the owner and i was running as rabbitmq user, it was a simple permission error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like it was a permissions error. all i did was run :

```
chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/
```

and it worked :D